# Array values to be display as per the condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have an array like

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
```

I need to display based on the following 2 conditions.

1) If I pass an array to a function like, function(array,2) then the array should display like `[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h],[i]]`.

2) If I pass an array to a function like, function(array,3) then the array should display like `[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]`.

How this can be achievable using javascript? Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post an example of the code you have to achieve the desired result. It's doable by iterating over initial array and pushing data to the result array.

Comment: Looks like the answer you're looking for is in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks